# Toggle columns in a table with colResizable using ng-hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created a simple directive that utilizes colResizable plugin that simply activates the plugin on a table after it is rendered:

```
app.directive("columnResizable", this.columnResizable = function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Initialize colResizable plugin after DOM
            $timeout(function() {
                element.colResizable({
                    liveDrag:true,
                    postbackSafe: true,
                    partialRefresh: true,
                    minWidth: 100
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This directive worked fine until I needed to adda feature to hide and show columns in the table. I use ng-hide and turn columns on or off by changing a localStorage boolean variable. The columns hide/show just as expected if I start from a "show all" state. But refuses to show if I start from a hidden state:

```
<button class="btn btn-default"
  ng-class="{active: emailHidden}"
  ng-click="emailHidden = !emailHidden">Hide Email</button>

<table column-resizable class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th ng-hide="emailHidden">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-if="!scheduleEntries || scheduleEntries.length == 0">
        <tr>
            <td>Foo Bar</td>
            <td ng-hide="emailHidden">foo@bar.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I created a plunker with regular boolean variable. If you change the $scope.emailHidden variable to start hidden, you can see that the Email column will not show when the button is clicked: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y20BH2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding a watcher for the emailHidden variable inside the directive, once changed, it resets the column widths and reinitializes the colResizable plugin:

```
scope.$watch('emailHidden', function(newVal) {
  element.find('th').css('width','auto');
    $timeout(function() {
        element.colResizable({
            liveDrag:true,
            postbackSafe: true,
            partialRefresh: true,
            minWidth: 100
        });
    });
});
```

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/09u9p5)

I appreciate it if anyone has a better way to work this out. Preferably something that doesn't involve $watch

Answer (score 0):

When `$scope.emailHidden` value is set to true, ColResizer updated the width of the second column to zero. And this width is not getting updated even after the `emailHidden` flag is set to false. As the second column is not having any width in this case, we are not able to see it on the screen.

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah I can see that.. Do you have a recommendation of how to handle that?